# iOS: How to save NSOrderedSet with app related user data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsorderedset

I need to save NSOrderedSet as a container for an inner NSDictionary objects. I tried to save the set to plist, but this class can't be saved here. Are there any other way to save it easily and don't go to Core Data jungle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the ordered set as an array:

```
NSOrderedSet *set = ... // your ordered set
NSArray *array = [set array];
// Now write the array to the plist
```

Later,

```
// read the array from the plist
NSArray *array = ... // array from plist
NSOrderedSet *set = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array];
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest way

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NSCoding`. I find it pretty handy.

Save:

```
NSArray *array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [array[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_set"];

NSOrderedSet *my_set = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:my_set toFile:path];
```

retrieve:

```
my_set = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

Comment: thank you for you answer I don't quite familiar with `NSCoding`, so I choose plist answer as the right one but your suitable too.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSOrderedSet `- (NSArray *)array`  method to get the array object and use NSArray's `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag` ,  to write to a plist file